# Swift error in fallback scratch context: error: failed to load module 'AppName'

Tags: swift, xcode

When I add a breakpoint in code, then I try to `po` something in `lldb` I get this error once, and it gets away after printing the variable again.

```
warning: Swift error in fallback scratch context: error: failed to load module 'AppName'


note: This error message is displayed only once. If the error displayed above is due to conflicting
search paths to Clang modules in different images of the debugged executable,
this can slow down debugging of Swift code significantly,
since a fresh Swift context has to be created every time a conflict is encountered.
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I think it happened after integrating CocoaPodsBinary

Comment: same annoying thing with me too :/